# Integrate jsTree within my mvc 4.0 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I have this Category object defined like so:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I then fictively create data like so:

```
public ICollection<Category> GetCategories()
{
    List<Category> lst = new List<Category>();
    //Top
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Car", Description = "Car", ParentCategoryId = 0 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Boats", Description = "Boats", ParentCategoryId = 0 });

    //Catalogs
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 3, Name = "Winter2012", Description = "Parts & Accessories", ParentCategoryId = 1 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 4, Name = "Gear2012", Description = "Gear", ParentCategoryId = 1 });

    //Categories
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 5, Name = "NewItems", Description = "New Stuff", ParentCategoryId = 3 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 6, Name = "Promo1", Description = "Promo1", ParentCategoryId = 3 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 7, Name = "Promo2", Description = "Promo2", ParentCategoryId = 3 });

    //Sub-Categories (if any)
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 8, Name = "Men", Description = "Men", ParentCategoryId = 5 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 9, Name = "Women", Description = "Women", ParentCategoryId = 5 });
    lst.Add(new Category { Id = 10, Name = "Kids", Description = "Kids", ParentCategoryId = 5 });

    return lst;
}
```

I’m trying to build a checkbox TreeView and currently looking at the jsTree plugin.
In the end, the treeview looks somewhat like:
Top-->Catalogs-->Categories-->Sub-Categories

---

In my Controller, I fill a ViewModel (HomeModel) and then call the View.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Data.Data d = new Data.Data();
    var customerGroups = d.GetCustomerGroups();

    var model = new HomeModel();
    model.CategoryStructure = d.GetCategories();

    return View(model);
}
```

The HomeModel  is define like so:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    //The checkbox hierarchy structure.
    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoryStructure { get; set; }

    //The selected category Id's once submitted.
    public IEnumerable<int> CategorySelectList { get; set; }        
}
```

The View is, of course, strongly typed to the HomeModel and looks somewhat like this:

```
…some html…
<div id="tree">
    <ul id="treeview">
    @CategoryTree(Model.CategoryStructure, 0)
    </ul>
</div>
…some html…

@helper CategoryTree(IEnumerable<Category> nodes, int? parentId)
{
    if (nodes.Any(n => n.ParentCategoryId == parentId)) 
    { 
    <ul>
        @foreach (var node in nodes.Where(n => n.ParentCategoryId == parentId)) 
        {
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="CategorySelectList" id="@node.Id" value="@node.Id" /> <label for="@node.Id">@node.Description</label>
                @CategoryTree(nodes, node.Id)
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
}
```

Everything works great! I have this beautiful list of `<ul>’s and <li>’s` nicely formatted.
After setting up all the necessary jsTree files, I do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#treeview").jstree();
    });
    //]]>
</script>
```

The jsTree plugin seems to apply nicely to my manually built treeview but the basic “clicking a parent node does not check/select all the child nodes”.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add in your `jstree` script in order to get the checkboxes working fine:

```
$("#tree").jstree({
    checkbox: {
        real_checkboxes: true,
        real_checkboxes_names: function (n) { 
            return [("check_" + (n[0].id || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000))), n[0].id] 
        }
    },
    plugins: ["html_data", "types", "themes", "ui", "checkbox"]
});
```

Your checkboxes will have the Id of the `li` statement so you don't have to add them manually. When checked, the Ids will be submitted automatically within the `FormCollection`.